# Google Charts - Scale in Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I use **Material column charts** in my Web App.

and I have following out

[image]

and codes are below,

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Structure', 'Estimated', 'Actual'],
              ['hours', 6, 8],
              ['hours2', 20, 18],                              
            ]);

            var options = {
              chart: {
                title: 'Structures by Hours',
                subtitle: 'Estimated vs Actual',
              }
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_hours'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
```

**What I want to do two things / need your hand,** (on red circled area the image.)

1. to name the Y-Axis as **Hours**
2. and make the same axis scale 2 hours by 2 hours so that the Y-Axis / Hours Axis become 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 so on.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to set [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for the `vAxis`.

```
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Hours',
        ticks: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
    }
```

1. Use `title` for the axis label.
2. Supply an array to `ticks` for the axis tick marks.

However, it doesn't appear `ticks` works for Material charts.
Note the options have to be converted as well...
`google.charts.Bar.convertOptions`

This example shows both a Core chart and a Material chart...

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar'],
  callback: drawBarChart
});

function drawBarChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Structure', 'Estimated', 'Actual'],
        ['hours', 6, 8],
        ['hours2', 20, 18],
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Structures by Hours',
            subtitle: 'Estimated vs Actual',
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Hours',
            ticks: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_hours'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_hours2'));
    chart2.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="columnchart_hours"></div>
<div id="columnchart_hours2"></div>
```